# How to prove the following conjecture.

Tags: asymptotics

Prove

> if $d(n)$ is $O(f(n))$ and $e(n)$ is $O(g(n))$, then $d(n) + e(n)$ is $O((f(n) + g(n)))$.

What I tried.

if $d(n)$ is $O(f(n))$ then $d(n) \leq c_1 \cdot f(n)$
if $e(n)$ is $O(g(n))$ then $e(n) \leq c_2 \cdot f(n)$

which implies $d(n) + e(n) \leq c_1\cdot f(n) + c_2\cdot g(n)$.

I am unable to proceed further than this. Please help.

Comment: Hint: $\max(c_1,c_2)$

Comment: ok so c1.f(n) + c2.g(n) <= max(c1,c2) (f(n) + g(n)) so it becomes O(f(n) + g(n)) where c = max(c1,c2)

Comment: What do you mean exactly by $\max(f(n)+g(n))$? Taking the max of just one argument doesn't make sense.